# How do I log a Request Variable on a classic ASP page to a local document?

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on an older system that uses classic ASP pages. The effort is to process "vanity" URL requests based on a server variable that is passed to the page. The page then takes that variable, and redirects you to the correct page based on that variable and a Select Case statement. I have not been successful in located how to "create a log" of what Server Variable is being used on the page to redirect someone. Basically, I want to be able to measure each vanity's usage.

```
<%
   HostHeader = (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"))
   Select Case lcase(HostHeader)
   case "xxx" Response.Redirect("http://some.url/")
...
?>
```

I would like to be able to take the HostHeader, as well as the current date/time, and save it to a file local on the server.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit 1**
I've set up the code, it errors out on the OpenTextFile line..

```
HostHeader = (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"))
Select Case lcase(HostHeader)

dim fs
dim f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("/log/log.txt"),8,true)
f.WriteLine(HostHeader)
f.Close
set f=Nothing
set fs=Nothing
```

Comment: At a high level, you will need a function that uses `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `TextStream`to work with files. To map to the file on the local path, you will have to use `Server.MapPath` assuming you have the file under your virtual directory and/or you have access to the path.

Comment: So far, I've done this. It was erroring out, so I went line by line, and it errors on OpenTextFile.

See edit 1 above...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. IISUSR did not have permission to the folder. Thank you!!! :)